# multiple controls accessing same web service

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I have two controls on one form that access the same web service.  If I hook everything up the webservice stops working.  I'm wondering if this is possible, that is multiple controls calling the same web service, or it was in fact not designed to do this.  If it is, then what do I 'tweak' in order to get it to work?

Thanks.

Comment: You know, some code will help. You may have issues on the client side, some javascript error and timing issues (eg, before you get replay, you send new request).

Comment: Shouldn't matter.  What do you mean by "stops working", "controls", "form", whatever?  A bit more background will help.

Comment: Dax, if i have only one control calling the web service then it works perfectly, but as soon as I add the second control then nothing happens.  If i switch to debug mode then break points inside the web service are never hit.  That's why i'm curious to know if you can indeed hook two control up to the web service.  As I said, and this is really for Aristos, one control works perfectly.